# Repeating call to function based on its callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following setup:

```
const foo = () => {
  bar((err,payload) => {
     // some stuff happens here
  }
}
```

So I need to continuously call "bar" inside of "foo" until a certain outcome happens in the "some stuff happens here" part. But I obviously have to wait for the outcome of the callback before re-calling "bar" - how could I structure this?

Comment: promises or async/await would be easier, do you have that option?

Comment: the "bar" function is not written by me, and only has callbacks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the new [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in ES6.

```
const foo = async () => {
    var myOutcome;
    while (/*CHECK HERE*/) {
        try {
            myOutcome = await /* call async javascript function here */
        } catch (e) {
            // Handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

This all relies on [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so long as that function returns a promise it will automatically be run more of a synchronous like manner.

**Edit** if the function only supports callbacks you can wrap it in a promise like so.

```
function myCallbackFunctionPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        callbackFunction((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why await inside the loop? Shouldn't it be done after the condition is satisfied which would be outside the while loop?

Comment: Based on the question asked it sounds like the OP is wanting to wait for a callback to be fulfilled, then check to see if that outcome matches something. If so rerun it, if not move on.

Comment: @BruceM Just edited with an example of how you would create a wrapper function to wrap a callback function within a promise to use the await syntax with.

Comment: thanks, will give that a go - i am needing to learn how to use promises, this is a good opportunity

Comment: @BruceM Awesome. Glad it helped! Happy coding!!